# scipy.optimize.curve_fit not working for some functions

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I have tried using the curve_fit function from the `scipy.optimize` package to fit a set of simulated data to find the curie temperature of CoFeB. However, what I have tried is not fitting the data. The function (`curie_func` in the code below) should work and I have tested plotting it with realistic values as initial parameters (`p0`) to demonstrate it fitting well. The fit parameters I get as the output of `curve_fit` are
`array([ nan,  nan])` 
and the covariance matrix is:

```
array([[ inf,  inf],[ inf,  inf]])
```

Here is the code demonstrating the `curve_fit` function fitting random data (a parabola) and not fitting the simulation data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import random as rd

def func(x,Tc,B):
    return Tc*(x**2)+B

x = np.array([i for i in np.arange(-100,100,10)])
y = np.array([func(i,0.1,64)+rd.gauss(0,50) for i in x])

popt1 = opt.curve_fit(func,x[:-5],y[:-5])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x,y,'k.')

curve_fit_x = np.arange(min(x),max(x),0.1)
curve_fit_y = [func(i,*popt1[0]) for i in curve_fit_x]

ax1.plot(list(curve_fit_x),list(curve_fit_y),'b')


x  =['0', '40', '80', '120', '160', '200', '240', '280', '320', '360', '400', '440', '480', '520', '560', '600', '640', '680', '720', '760', '800', '840', '880', '920', '960', '1000', '1040', '1080', '1120', '1160', '1200', '1240', '1280', '1320', '1360', '1400']
y = ['1', '0.983289', '0.965702', '0.946315', '0.933125', '0.905639', '0.890218', '0.871013', '0.853052', '0.841008', '0.796679', '0.783795', '0.746877', '0.720693', '0.715963', '0.702506', '0.654126', '0.593997', '0.595407', '0.552495', '0.524943', '0.481418', '0.425329', '0.378469', '0.360465', '0.247084', '0.197054', '0.121997', '0.0450571', '0.0513379', '0.0572443', '0.00990522', '0.0319629', '0.0105687', '0.0173795', '0.0322641']

x = np.array([int(i) for i in x])
y = np.array([float(i) for i in y])

def curie_func(x,Tc,B):
    return (1-(x/Tc))**B


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

popt2 = opt.curve_fit(curie_func,x[:-5],y[:-5])
ax2.plot(x,y,'k.')

curve_fit_x = np.arange(min(x),max(x),0.1)
curve_fit_y = [curie_func(i,*popt2[0]) for i in curve_fit_x]

ax2.plot(list(curve_fit_x),list(curve_fit_y),'b')

plt.show()
```

When I use the parameters `p0=(1150,0.57)` in the `curve_fit` function it doesn't optimise the parameters at all just outputs the initial parameters back to the console. The plot below shows the `curve_fit` function not working (the bottom graph) and it working (top graph).

[image: Curve_fit function not working]

The second picture demonstrates the `curie_temp` function is the correct function for the data, and would fit it if the `curve_fit` worked.

[image: The curie_temp function is correct, but the curve_fit won't optimise the parameters]

*Edit: The errors outputted on running (with initial parameters) are:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return (-1+(x/Tc))**B

Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return (-1+(x/Tc))**B

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return (-1+(x/Tc))**B

Comment: Did you notice the warning that is printed when you run the code?  That is an important detail, and you should include it in the question.  The problem is that for some value in the numpy array `x`, `1 - (x/Tc)` becomes negative, the expression `(1-(x/Tc))**B` results in `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt`, and the numerical result of that calculation is `nan`.  You'll have to find some way to ensure that you don't attempt to raise a negative value to a non-integer power.

Comment: @Warren Thank you, I see that now! I don't suppose you know any way to get around this? I assume python here will need to deal complex numbers? Is there anyway to make the curve_fit function do this?

Comment: Actually sorry, that comment really helped. I decided to use a high value of Tc (2000) as an initial parameter so it would try to converge from high values and the bit in the bracket (1-(x/Tc)) was always positive and it worked. Thanks!